# c# API request for WhosOff not working

Tags: c#, json, api

I am trying to connect to an API, via C# and WinForms, to download some data from a server. I am using the latest version of visual studio (2017 at the time of writing).

**The API I am using:** https://www.whosoff.com/features/api/

As per the API setup, I have already got an authentication key and my IP has been white listed.

**What I have so far:**

```
try{    
var request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://wr1.whosoff.com/api/whosoff?start_date=01-Apr-2018&end_date=25-Apr-2018");
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.Headers.Add("AUTH-KEY", "MY_AUTH_KEY");

                var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                string content = string.Empty;
                using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        content = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
} catch(Exception ex){
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

This does not work - it throws an exception; *"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."*

I can connect to other sites API's using this format - can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

So it turns out the issue was with TLS certificates and the fact that the API services requires TLS 1.2, which by default is turned off. It can be enabled by inserting the following code into your project

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

After inserting this code, everything worked as expected.

**ORIGINAL POST**

For anyone that is interested; the code above DID in fact work. It turns out that debug mode within Visual Studio causes this weird behavior - how and why I am not sure.

But when running the EXE file directly from the debug folder; it worked fine.

Weird. Anyway I ended up changing to Newtonsoft.JSON and using the following code;

```
 var client = new RestSharp.RestClient("API URL");
 /* Create a new request to send to the client */
 var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest(RestSharp.Method.GET); 
 /* Add the correct headers for authentication and format */
 request.AddHeader("AUTH-KEY", "MY KEY");
 request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
 /* Get the response */
 var response = client.Execute(request);
 var content = response.Content;
```